# What is Connectivity method in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

[image]

Can anyone explain "What is Connectivity method in Azure SQL Database" Below are the three connectivity method.
    No access
    Public endpoint
    Private endpoint (preview)

Comment: Have you clicked (i) that just right of the (*)?

Comment: Not really a stack overflow question, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ilkerkaran: yes i have but didn't get the satisfactory answer.

Comment: that (i) popup doesn't explain anything that you wouldn't already know.

Answer (score 0):

[Public endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-public-endpoint-securely) for a managed instance enables data access to your managed instance from outside the virtual network. You are able to access your managed instance from multi-tenant Azure services like Power BI, Azure App Service, or an on-premises network. By using the public endpoint on a managed instance, you do not need to use a VPN, which can help avoid VPN throughput issues.

Private endpoint connections are associated with a private IP address within a Virtual Network. Note that private endpoint connections are defined at the server level and they provide access to all databases in the server. You can learn more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview).